# Apply style to all contained elements and the element itself

Tags: html, css

In a CSS stylesheet, I would like to apply a style to all descendants of an element (identified by `id="outer"`), *as well as the element itself*. Is there a more succinct or DRY way to do it than this:

```css
#outer, #outer * {
    border: medium solid;
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty succinct to me.

Comment: @j08691 - something tweaks me about repeating the `#outer` selector twice (it would be worse if that selector was more complex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There isn't. That is as succinct as it gets.